# Python, outputting Two lists with a common column into a file (TXT or CSV)

Tags: python, unix, csv

Let's consider that I have two lists

Person 1 :

```
    2012-08      person 1             23
    2012-09      person 1             63 
    2012-10      person 1             99  
    2012-11      person 1             62
```

and

Person  2 :

```
    2012-08      person 2             45
    2012-09      person 2             69 
    2012-10      person 2             12  
    2012-11      person 2             53
```

What's your suggestion if I'de like to have a tabular data with the following pattern:

```
Date        Person 1       Person 2
-----       ---------      ---------
2012-08      23             45
2012-09      63             69 
2012-10      99             12  
2012-11      62             53
```

***UPDATE***:

Here is the list :

```
List1 = [(u'201206', u'Customer_1', 0.19048299999999993), (u'201207', u'Customer_1', 15.409000999998593), (u'201208', u'Customer_1', 71.1695730000299), (u'201209', u'Customer_1', 135.73918600011424), (u'201210', u'Customer_1', 235.26299999991522), (u'201211', u'Customer_1', 271.768984999485), (u'201212', u'Customer_1', 355.90968299883934), (u'201301', u'Customer_1', 508.39194049821526), (u'201302', u'Customer_1', 631.136656500077), (u'201303', u'Customer_1', 901.9127695088399), (u'201304', u'Customer_1', 951.9143960094264)]

List 2 = [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (u'201301', u'Customer_2', 3.7276289999999657), (u'201302', u'Customer_2', 25.39122749999623), (u'201303', u'Customer_2', 186.77777299985306), (u'201304', u'Customer_2', 387.97834699805617)]
```

Comment: How are those lists formatted? Are they coming from *other* CSV files? Can you give us lists in python syntax?

Comment: Actually this the last stage of processing of some massive CSV files . Yes, I've extracted each list from a relevant CSV file and would like to combine them based on the mentioned criteria and output them to a final text/csv file...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll put the lists soon .. let me run it again .. it takes 2-3 minutes .. (~ 2.5 GB of data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to combine two input sequences *while processing*:

```
import itertools

reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
reader2 = csv.reader(file2)

for row1, row2 in itertools.izip(reader1, reader2):
    # process row1 and row2 together.
```

This will work with lists too; `izip()` makes merging of long lists efficient; it is the iterator version of the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which, in python 2, materializes the whole combined list in memory.

If you can possibly retool the functions that create your input lists into generators, use that:

```
def function_for_list1(inputfilename):
    with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            # process row
            yield row

def function_for_list2(inputfilename):
    with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            # process row
            yield row

for row1, row2 in itertools.izip(function_for_list1(somename), function_for_list2(someothername)):
    # process row1 and row2 together
```

This arrangement makes that you can process gigabytes of information while only holding in memory what you need to process one small set of rows.

Comment: Thanks.. And if I have the lists ready to use, May I swap (reader1 and reader 2) with the actual lists?? Because, those lists are extracted from a pretty complicated process.. It was not just reading them actually.

Comment: @Eric: Certainly, but you should try to avoid building the lists in memory if you can. You could use generators too, for example; functions that use loops and `yield` to produce the next value from the complex process for their input source, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=[ ['2012-08','person 1',23], ['2012-09','person 1',63], 
        ['2012-10','person 1',99], ['2012-11','person 1',62]]

l2=[ ['2012-08','person 2',45], ['2012-09','person 2',69],
['2012-10','person 2',12], ['2012-11','person 2',53]]

h1 = { x:z for x,y,z in l1}
h2 = { x:z for x,y,z in l2}

print "{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}".format("Date", "Person 1", "Person 2")
print "{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}".format('-'*5, '-'*8, '-'*8)
for d in sorted(h1): print "{:<10} {:<10}{:<10}".format(d,h1[d],h2[d])
```

**Output**

```
Date      Person 1  Person 2  
-----     --------  --------  
2012-08    23        45        
2012-09    63        69        
2012-10    99        12        
2012-11    62        53
```

Answer (score 0):

If Python is not a requirement, and the generation of the two CSV files happens in a plain old bash script, you can combine `join` and `awk` (or even `cut`).

Example:

Let's say this file is called `one`:

```
2012-08 person1 23
2012-09 person1 63 
2012-10 person1 99  
2012-11 person1 62
```

and this file is called `two`:

```
2012-08 person2 45
2012-09 person2 69 
2012-10 person2 12  
2012-11 person2 53
```

Then the command

```
join one two | awk '{print $1 " " $3 " " $5}'
```

will output:

```
2012-08 23 45
2012-09 63 69
2012-10 99 12
2012-11 62 53
```

To put the CSV headers on the output, or to choose a different delimiter, is not difficult.

Note that one caveat is that the two files must be sorted on the join column for this to work.  But you probably already know this, because you say the two CSV files are massive.  Therefore you do not want to read them all into memory at once, probably.  Plain Unix tools are really good for this sort of thing, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I have to do it in python ... it's a part of  a pythonic system ..

Comment: No problem.  Hopefully your files are sorted by date and `itertools.zip` works for you, then!  It's so much more helpful timewise and spacewise to output the rows while you are reading in the input rows.